# loading a codeigniter view through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am experimenting with AJAX the jQuery way. For a start I copied  a code
   from w3school. It worked fine.

Then I put the code in a view page in Codeigniter and put the server side page in the views folder.
   It doesn't work.
   I am certain that the problem is with the url.

This is the code that works in a regular php project but when copied to a Codeigniter view it doesn't:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I think the problem has got to do with the URL and how codeigniter framework handles the URL. How should I write the URL for this to work correctly?

Comment: where is your `.txt` file located? also look at the [`base_url()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper function

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the view in a controller then you can load that controller with jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#div1").load("controllerName",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
        if(statusTxt=="success")
          alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt=="error")
          alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 Though it could work with separate files (without a controller) if .htaccess and/or routing is properly set.